# How do you do time series cross-validation using python?

Tags: time-series, machine-learning, cross-validation, python

Also, any tutorials/blogs available that you are aware of?

Answer (score 2):

Rob Hyndman outlines one approach [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/5/) and [here with a survey reference](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/crossvalidation/). Both are towards the end of the links. It seems pretty straight forward to implement in Python.

Comment: Is essentially what is being said in the  http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/crossvalidation/ excerpt that you should take a portion of the data and fit the model and the remaining portion of the data subtract the predicted value on the new observation from the true value  to get the error?